# Pluralizing a thing expressed by a quoted or hyphenated phrase, e.g. better-than-nothing or "better than nothing"

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, idioms

I found myself writing

> And so, they went on amassing better-than-nothing's.

because I wanted *better-than-nothing* to be a kind of catchphrase, referred to in this form consistently throughout my writing. I imagined alternatives such as

> And so, they went on amassing better-than-nothings.
>
> And so, they went on amassing *better-than-nothing*s.
>
> And so, they went on amassing "better-than-nothings."
>
> And so, they went on amassing "better-than-nothing"s.

I know the last example is clearly wrong, but, is the one that makes the most *sense* to me: grouping the phrase and pluralizing that group.

Is there a clearly *right* way to do this?

(I imagine not.) I'm interested in what's most natural to read ("idiomatic," I think is the word), and also interested in knowing what others have seen in similar instances. I'm afraid what's natural to *me* may not be what's natural to most others.

---

I'm also curious how one would treat a similar but more awkward phrase, *better-than-expected*.

> The vacation was full of better-than-expected's.

(A bad example, off the top of my head.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntactically, the phrase *better-than-nothing* is an adjective. As such, it does not take a plural.

But adjectives can be used as nouns (just as nouns can be used as adjectives). Generally the adjective refers to an implied noun made clear by context.

> When selecting among the various colors, he chose the *blue* [one/color].

When used as a noun, an adjective can be pluralized in the same manner as most nouns, by simply adding **s**.

> > When selecting among the various colors, he chose the *blues*.

If the context of your usage for *better-than-nothing* uses it like a noun, it should be pluralized in the same way.

> She wanted something better, but she settled for *better-than-nothing*.
>
> She sought better things, but often settled for *better-than-nothings*.

If you are merely reporting on the existence of the term *better-than-nothing*, then it takes on a noun-like meaning of its own.

> He counted the times the term "*better-than-nothing*" appeared in the text.
>
> There were ten "*better-than-nothings*" in each chapter.

The correct way to pluralize the term is to simply add an **s**.  The use of an **'s** suggest either possessive or a contraction.

If you are cataloging the term, rather than using it for its meaning, add quotation marks around the whole term (including the **s** when it is plural).

Similarly, if you are effectively defining or establishing a catchphrase, you can set it off in quotes (usually only the first time it is used), again with the **s** inside the quotes if plural.